# Shell script - match a value in a specific named field

Tags: bash, shell, unix

For example, let us suppose we have a following line:

```
RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail
```

Here test, slave, owners, time and status are different properties. 
The number of properties can vary, i.e., another property like category=xyz can be present or some property might not be present.

I am looking for a regular expression that matches if "owners=" contains a particular owner, say "own2". Also, this regular expression should not match other occurrences in the line. For example line can be:

```
RESULT: test=own2 slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail
```

Regular expression should not match own2 for "test" property.

I spent hours searching but failed :(

I looked for regular expressions with egrep. I tried the following:

```
line="RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail"
echo $line | egrep "owners=*own2*"
```

This failed to return any value. I am not getting what is wrong with my regular expression.

I am looking for something that works on all Unix flavors like Linux, AIX, Solaris, etc.

**EDIT - NOW WITH EXAMPLE**

Thank you very much for your responses!

Let me explain with more clearer example:

Contents of myfile:

```
blabla  
blaaaaaa some text  
RESULT: test=abcgrp1 slave=def owners=test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail  

some more blabla  
xyze  
RESULT: test=abc1 slave=def owners=grp1,test time=32 status=pass  

some text here  
RESULT: test=abc2 slave=def owners=gr,grp1 time=32 status=pass
```

I want to get tests whose status is "pass" and whose "owner" is "grp1" or "grp2"
So, initially, I wrote:

```
grep RESULT myfile | grep "pass" | egrep "grp1|gpr2"
```

It didn't take much time to realize that this is not correct as it returns true for the first "RESULT" line in "myfile".

So, I thought of writing like this:

```
grep RESULT myfile | grep "pass" | egrep "owners=grp1|owners=gpr2"
```

Obviously, this will fail for the third "RESULT" line in "myfile".

So, I need a regular expression which matches only if the pattern is present anywhere in the "owners" list.

NOTE: "owners" list is comma-separated if it has multiple owners. Else, it has only one value. Eg: owners=abc

Hope my problem is more clear now.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between regular expressions and filename wildcards.

Comment: even you used regex `.*own2.*`, this regex may work for the given example. but it is not reliable. what if there is user `own21,own22,own222,fooown2...` I think you got what I mean.

Comment: If you intend it to be compatible with most shells I don't think this should have been tagged as `bash`. Also, depending on what you like to do with your texts, I think it would be better if you use Awk. We could help more if you give us more details about e.g. how you get your lines with a command and how you plan to process the keys/values found on those lines.

Comment: @konsolebox thanks, added few more details to the post!

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```
$ cat file
RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail
```

This grep expression just shows the content after `owners=`:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=owners=)\w+' file
own1
```

If doesn't matter if the file contains more info:

```
$ cat file
RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,hello=3,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail, more things
$ grep -Po '(?<=owners=)\w+' file
own1
```

With this text, then you can proceed with the `if` condition:

```
if [[ "$(grep -Po '(?<=owners=)\w+' file)" == *own1* ]]; then
   echo "it is there"
fi
```

test:

```
$ if [[ "$(grep -Po '(?<=owners=)\w+' file)" == *own1* ]]; then echo "it is there"; fi
it is there
```

Comment: as far as I understood, OP wants to check if the owners value contains some string. instead of extracting the values

Comment: Hi @Kent. yes, I was updating with a proper answer :) Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
echo "$line" | grep -E '\<owners=([[:alnum:]]+,)*own2($|[, ])'
```

This will find any string containing owners value with comma separated values containing own2

Comment: Out of these answers, this is the closest to a sane solution, but it requires anchors and proper quoting. `echo "$line"` with double quotes, `egrep '\<owners=([[:alnum:]]+,)*own2[, ]'`.

Comment: You want `egrep "owners=([:alnum:]*,)*own2(,[:alnum:]*)* "`

Comment: @tripleee you can always edit someones answer if you think its close but contain some mistakes, and thanks for upgrading the solution

Comment: [Editing code is discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code) but I took your response as an invitation to go ahead anyway. Feel free to rollback if there was a miscommunication, obviously.

Comment: @tripleee well, I didn't know about that, thanks. And again thanks for upgrade of my answar.

Comment: @jthill: the POSIX character class requires double square brackets `[[:alnum:]]`, or maybe you were trying to say `[[:alnum:],]`?

Comment: @tripleee no, my error, it's the doubles.  thanks for giving the correction it so it doesn't just hang there, really.

Comment: Still, it's simpler to just look for the proper end of value.

Answer (score 1):

#### Pure bash solution:

```
line='RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail'

declare -A allValues
while read -r -d ' ' curValue; do
    IFS='=' read key value <<< "${curValue}"
    allValues["$key"]=$value
done <<< "${line#RESULT: } "
```

This creates a nice associative array. Now it is very easy to get any value:

```
echo "${allValues[slave]}" # prints 'def'
echo "${allValues[owners]}" # prints 'own1,test,own2,newown'
```

Now, to see if `own2` is really there you can use `=~` :

```
if [[ ${allValues[owners]} =~ own2 ]]; then
```

Or using globs:

```
if [[ ${allValues[owners]} = *own2* ]]; then
```

### EDIT:

Whoops!

Imagine data like this: `owners=own1,test,thisown2iswrong,newown`
Both previous solutions are going to return `true` which is probably not what you want.
Here is a better regexp:

```
if [[ ${allValues[owners]} =~ (^|,)own2(,|$) ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
echo "RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail" | grep "owners=[^ ]*own2"
```

Example:

```
$ echo "RESULT: test=abc slave=def owners=own1,test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail" | grep -Po "owners=\K[^ ]*own[0-9]"
own1,test,own2
```

You perhaps wanted to say:

```
echo $line | egrep "owners=.*own2.*"
```

(note the extra `.`s in the pattern)

Comment: This will match `owners=fred,barney status=clown24`.

Comment: Eh, I thought that was handled (see first two examples)

Comment: Still you're hitting `owners=clown24` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This script requires GNU Awk (gawk).

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

function parse_file(file,  a, count, id, key, text, values) {
    FS = " "
    id = 0
    while ((getline < file) > 0) {
        if (!/^[[:blank:]]*$/) {
            text = ""
            do {
                if (/^RESULT: /) {
                    tests[id] = text
                    tests_results[id] = $0
                    count = split($0, props)
                    for (i = 2; i <= count; ++i) {
                        match(props[i], /([^=]+)=?(.*)/, a)
                        key = a[1]; values = a[2]
                        if (length(tests_props[id])) {
                            tests_props[id] = tests_props[id] "|" key
                        } else {
                            tests_props[id] = key
                        }
                        tests_props[id "|" key] = values
                    }
                    break
                } else {
                    if (length(text)) {
                        text = text "\n" $0
                    } else {
                        text = $0
                    }
                }
            } while ((getline < file) > 0)
            ++id
        }
    }
    tests_count = id
}

function get_values(id, key, var,  a, i, t, v) {
    v = tests_props[id "|" key]
    split(v, a, /,/)
    delete var
    for (i = 1; i in a; ++i) {
        t = a[i]
        var[t] = t
    }
}

function print_test(id) {
    print "--------------------"
    print tests[id]
    print tests_results[id]
    print "--------------------"

}

BEGIN {
    parse_file(ARGV[1])
    for (i in tests) {
        get_values(i, "owners", owners)
        get_values(i, "status", status)
        if (("grp1" in owners || "grp2" in owners) && "pass" in status) {
            print_test(i)
        }
    }
    exit
}
```

Sample file:

```
blabla  
blaaaaaa some text  
RESULT: test=abcgrp1 slave=def owners=test,own2,newown time=32 status=fail  

some more blabla  
xyze  
RESULT: test=abc1 slave=def owners=grp1,test time=32 status=pass  

some text here  
RESULT: test=abc2 slave=def owners=gr,grp1 time=32 status=pass  

some more blabla  
xyze  
RESULT: test=abc1 slave=def owners=grp1,test time=32 status=pass
```

Running `gawk -f script.awk sample.txt` gives:

```
--------------------
some more blabla  
xyze  
RESULT: test=abc1 slave=def owners=grp1,test time=32 status=pass  
--------------------
--------------------
some text here  
RESULT: test=abc2 slave=def owners=gr,grp1 time=32 status=pass  
--------------------
--------------------
some more blabla  
xyze  
RESULT: test=abc1 slave=def owners=grp1,test time=32 status=pass
--------------------
```

The code should be easy to customize at your own requirement. Just ask me if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your insights and answers.

Following yielded the result:

```
grep RESULT myfile | grep "pass" | egrep \(\(owners=\)*\(grp1\)\|\(owners=\)*\(grp2\)\)
```

From this what I understood is

1) When you have multiple pieces of patterns, enclose them in parenthesis

2) If there are multiple such patterns, they should be separated by a pipe and there should be another parenthesis covering all the patterns

If there is only one such pattern, the covering parenthesis is optional. This worked on all the platforms I tested viz., AIX, HPUX, LINUX, SOLARIS and NT.